# Why the gray-scale image is different from value channel of HSV image?

Tags: python, image, opencv

I have an image and convert it to gray-scale image. I also convert the original image into HSV color space. When I get the value channel of the HSV image, I expect to get the same thing as the gray-scale image. But, they are different! My question is am I doing something wrong or these two are basically different and if so, why?

Here is a piece of code in python, using opencv:

```
image=cv2.imread('someImage.jpg')
gray_image=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
hsv_image=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
hsv_image[:,:,2]-gray_image
```

I expect to get all zeros in the last line, but I don't!

Comment: Did you look at the documentation and see how the values for `V` and `Gray` are calculated?

Comment: Thank you for your comment and sorry for my late reply. I saw that before, and you are right the formulas are different, and obviously, one would get different results. The problem is when you look at different resources, people usually say that gray-scale and v channel of HSV color space are basically the same. But, technically they are not, as their conversion formulas are different. In terms of application, in some cases, you would get the same result, but they are situations that using gray-scale and v channel of HSV makes a difference because of different conversion algorithms.

Comment: Okay, so I guess I'm not quite sure what your question is, then. Value and grayscale are both measures of the brightness of an image, but mathematically they are not identical, as you have found. Perhaps this will help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Lightness